# SQL Pivot not summing all results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I had a go at making a SQL PIVOT recently, and I've discovered it's not quite working right. Here's what I'm using

SQL Server 2005
Vendor database using vendor views - i can't create extra tables or views or query the data tables directly (long story)

I am querying one set of data with multiple entries per month, and unioning it with a second set to make what i'll call a dataset.  I'm using CASE WHEN to group objects (i.e. results with dbid 1, 7 and 10 are 'a', 2,3 and 9 are 'b' etc.

I am pivoting the dataset to show the sum of volumes by month.

My problem is for one of the columns, it's not counting all the results in the dataset for what appears to be one month in the year.  On closer investigation, I see the data thats missing appears to be where two rows of data have the same value for N_Entered in the query below).

I've managed to recreate the problem using a generic query (below).   I've run this on sql server express 2008 r2 and sql server 2005 and i get the same results - which are

Begin_Time  Totals  A Apples    B Banana Bananas    C Carrot Carrots    D Dog Dogs
2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 174732  44000   4591    581 208

The sum of B for February 2014 is 4594, but this query returns 4591.  You'll note two entries for 'B' for february in table one have '3' as N_Entered.

If I remove the section that unions the dataset with table2 - I get the correct answer - 4594.

My $1m question(s) are

1. How can I get the correct results in a pivot?
2. For my own learning - what did I do wrong?

Differences between this code and my production query are

I select from views in production instead of using table variables
Results in production span over a year, I just left the 'datediff clause as is to try and keep it as close as possible.

Thank you very much!

```
declare @vartable as table (Begin_Time DateTime, Letter varchar(30), N_Entered int) 
declare @vartable2 as table (Begin_Time DateTime, Letter varchar(30), N_Entered int) 

--populate first table
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'D', 125) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 2519) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 23) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 271) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 9) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 3) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values  ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 37) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 357) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 24230) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 9) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'D', 83) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 1998) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 13) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 217) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 3) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 1) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'B', 24) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 212) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 18656) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'A', 12) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'C', 272) 
insert into @vartable (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'C', 309) 

--populate second table
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T',  1009) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 90810) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 198) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 253) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 447) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 829) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 80427) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 152) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 149) 
insert into @vartable2 (Begin_Time, Letter, N_Entered) Values ('2014-02-01 00:00:00', 'T', 458) 

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Begin_Time, 
CASE Letter 
        WHEN 'A' THEN 'A Apples' 
        WHEN 'B' THEN 'B Banana Bananas' 
        WHEN 'C' THEN 'C Carrot Carrots' 
        WHEN 'D' THEN 'D Dog Dogs' 
ELSE Letter 
END 'Option Selected' 
, N_Entered 
From @vartable 
WHERE (Datediff(month, begin_time, getdate()) Between 1 and 12) 
AND Letter IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' )  -- end first select 

--removing this union section does give the right answer

UNION 
( 
SELECT Begin_Time, 'Totals' as 'Total Numbers', Sum(N_Entered) As N_Entered 
        FROM @vartable2 
                WHERE   

                          Letter IN ('T') 
                         AND (Datediff(month, begin_time, getdate()) Between 1 and 12) 
                GROUP BY begin_time 
        )  -- end second select 

-- end of union section

) As Data 

PIVOT 

( 
SUM(N_ENTERED) 
FOR [Option Selected] IN ([Totals], [A Apples], [B Banana Bananas], [C Carrot Carrots], [D Dog Dogs]) 
) 
As PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Union with Union ALL

Union is eliminating duplicate values i.e. value 3 from B. Union ALL considers it.